# Search variable text for some string

Tags: vba, ms-word

How can I search through a variable's text for some string?

In Excel VBA, if I wanted to strip the text `myTextVariable = "ii. The man walks away"` of the numeration, I could do

`myTextVariable = Left(myTextVariable,Search(".",myTextVariable))` which would effectively leave me with `"The man walks away"`.

How can I do that in Word? I tried something like `myTextVariable = left(myTextVariable, Find.Text = ".")` but that doesn't work.  Also tried like `myTextVariable.Content.Find.Execute(findText:=".")` to no avail.

The overall idea is I have an index with many entries:

```
Automobile - type of car
Art Deco - an art type from back in the day
USA - a country
ii.Australia -a continent
iv. Greenland - another continent
Greenland - an icy continent
```

And I'm looping through them, and want to remove any `i, ii, iii, iv, v, ..., x` before the text and can't figure how to do so.

Thanks for any ideas!

Edit: Thanks to @ScottCraner, I'm now using:

```
myTextVariable = myRange.Text
periodLoc = InStr(myTextVariable, ".")
If periodLoc < 10 And periodLoc > 0 Then
    finalText = Trim(Mid(myTextVariable, InStr(myTextVariable, ".") + 1)) ' Trim(Right(myTextVariable, Len(myTextVariable) - periodLoc))
Else
finalText = myRange.Text
End If
```

But now have an issue: sometimes the text will be `"The U.S. - a country blah"`, and this will cut out "The U.".  How can I search for ONLY if it's `i, ii, ..., x`?  Can I use RegEx with `InStr`? I could of course do an array with `i, ii, iii, etc` and loop through the array, but think that might not be the most efficient way.

Thanks to ScottCraner, I was able to get it with the below:

```
Private Sub add_Selection_to_Index(ByVal myRange As Word.Range)
Dim textToPeriod$, finalText$
Dim periodLoc&

Debug.Print "Selection: " & myRange.Text

textToPeriod = myRange.Text
periodLoc = InStr(textToPeriod, "i.")
If periodLoc < 10 And periodLoc > 0 Then
    finalText = Trim(Right(textToPeriod, Len(textToPeriod) - periodLoc - 1))
Else
    periodLoc = InStr(textToPeriod, "v.")
    If periodLoc < 10 And periodLoc > 0 Then
        finalText = Trim(Right(textToPeriod, Len(textToPeriod) - periodLoc - 1))    ' Trim(Mid(textToPeriod, InStr(textToPeriod, "v.")))
    Else
        periodLoc = InStr(textToPeriod, "x.")
        If periodLoc < 10 And periodLoc > 0 Then
            finalText = Trim(Right(textToPeriod, Len(textToPeriod) - periodLoc - 1))    'Trim(Mid(textToPeriod, InStr(textToPeriod, "x.")))
        Else
            finalText = myRange.Text
        End If
    End If

End If

ActiveDocument.Indexes.MarkEntry Range:=myRange, entry:=finalText, entryautotext:=finalText, crossreferenceautotext:="", _
                                 bookmarkname:="", Bold:=False, Italic:=False, reading:=""
Debug.Print "Index: " & finalText
End Sub
```

Comment: Should it not be right, instead of left? I prefer mid to right,  `myTextVariable =Mid(myTextVariable, Instr(myTextVariable,".")+1)`

Comment: @ScottCraner - I just had that idea too. I'm testing now and will report back.

Comment: @ScottCraner - It works great! The only thing now is I have to discern between `i.` and `U.S.` being at the start.  I know since `i.` is the start, I can narrow it down to be within the first 10 characters (hence my `If periodLoc < 10` line.  I'm thinking I can use Regex, but don't know if you can in `InStr` but will try.

Comment: You would only need to loop with `i.`,`v.` and `x.`.  all of the other 7 combinations will work looking only at strings of two.

Comment: @ScottCraner - Clever!! That's just what I did and it seems to be working. I've put my final code in my OP. If you want to make your comments into an answer, I'll happily mark it for you.

Comment: I'm okay, I was just fleshing out your ideas.

Comment: I reverted your edit. Adding [SOLVED] and solution to your post is not how this site works. If you want to indicate you've arrived at a solution and share that information, do so by writing an answer to the question in the space below. Answering your own question is totally acceptable here; you can even accept it as the correct solution (although you don't earn rep for doing so).

Comment: A lot depends on *exactly* what you need to eliminate. Just i,ii,ii,..,x? All roman numerals" or what?

Comment: @bibadia - Technically, it'd be all roman numerals.  Pratically, my document only goes up to `x`.  Of course, in the future I may need to look for `xi.` etc, but using `i.` should pick that up. It'd be more of an issue if I ever got to using `L`, or `MM`, which isn't likely at all.

Comment: Would using "i." correctly allow you to cconvert  "hi. blah, blah", to "blah, blah" for example?

Comment: @bibadia - good call. Hm, I'll have to think.  I'd like to use Regex so I can whittle this down better, but am not sure how to do that with `InStr()`.

Comment: "replace", "select.." and "split"(since VBA 5 or 6 only) may help. I am not your guy on regex :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With apologies to @ScottCraner, I had long ago worked with a [function to convert roman numerals to arabic](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?9300-Solved-convert-from-Roman-digit-to-Arabic-digit) and thought the above code might leverage that function. (Thanks to **mdmackkillop** for the use of the function there long ago.) Please copy that function into your module.

The following code should work for any roman-formatted number (as long as the roman number has fewer than ten characters - a safe bet)

```
Option Explicit

Function StripNumeration(ByVal myRange As Range) As String
    '--- assumes the myRange parameter value may contain leading roman
    '    numerals. Returns a string of the input text without the
    '    leading number
    Dim periodLoc As Long
    Dim numeration As String
    Dim returnText As String
    returnText = myRange.Text
    periodLoc = InStr(1, returnText, ".", vbTextCompare)
    If periodLoc < 10 And periodLoc > 0 Then
        numeration = Left(returnText, periodLoc - 1)
        If Arabic(numeration) <> "Fail" Then
            returnText = Right(returnText, Len(returnText) - periodLoc)
        End If
    Else
    End If
    StripNumeration = Trim(returnText)
End Function
```

Comment: my ego is not so big that I can't appreciate a better method.